# How to get a specific value out of an array for a custom object?

Tags: arrays, swift

Let's say we have a custom object:

```
public struct PosterData : Decodable {

  public let filePath : String
  public let aspectRatio : NSNumber
  public let height : NSNumber
  public let width : NSNumber

  public init?(json: JSON) {

    guard let filePath : String = "file_path"  <~~ json,
      let aspectRatio : NSNumber = "aspect_ratio" <~~ json,
      let height : NSNumber = "height" <~~ json,
      let width : NSNumber = "width" <~~ json
      else {return nil}

    self.filePath = filePath
    self.aspectRatio = aspectRatio
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
  }

}
```

And we have an array of that custom object:

```
var posters:[PosterData] = []
```

How can I iterate over the array to retrieve all instances of "filePath"?  I've tried this:

```
for poster in posters {

          self.updatePoster(extraPoster:posters[0].filePath)

        }
```

but all it does is give me the first object's "filepath" in the array and not the others.

Comment: `poster.filePath`?

Comment: That did it, I should have known that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `for poster in posters` it means you're going to iterate over posters, using `poster` as a variable for each iteration.  Every time you move to a new poster you can access it by using that `poster` variable.  So your code would look like this:

```
for poster in posters {
    self.updatePoster(extraPoster: poster.filePath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
posters.forEach { self.updatePoster(extraPoster: $0.filePath) }
```